# How to use tomcat9-maven-plugin

Tags: maven-plugin, tomcat9

I want to use tomcat9-maven-plugin in my maven project to start an embedded tomcat server so that I can test my web application.

Could anyone provide the demo how to use it in the pom.xml and run configurations in Intellij Idea?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working with the Cargo Maven3 Plugin

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
<artifactId>cargo-maven3-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.10.8</version>
<configuration>
    <container>

        <containerId>tomcat9x</containerId>
        <type>installed</type>

        <systemProperties>
            <property1>value1</property1>
        </systemProperties>

    </container>


    <deployables>
        <deployable>
            <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.company</groupId>
            <type>war</type>
            <location>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.war</location>
            <pingURL>http://127.0.0.1:8080/MYAPP</pingURL>
        </deployable>
    </deployables>

    <configuration>
        <type>existing</type>
        <home>C://DEVTOOLS//apache-tomcat-9.0.36</home>
    </configuration>

</configuration>

<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>start-server</id>
        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>start</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```